# AWS CLI syntax error: Error parsing parameter '--image': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am trying to follow a walkthrough involving using AWS to use live feed facial recognition (see link below). I have done the 7 previous steps without issue and am currently on step 8, where I have uploaded a picture to a S3 bucket, and I have to do the command in cmd:

`aws rekognition index-faces --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"<S3BUCKET>","Name":"<MYFACE_KEY>.jpeg"}}' --collection-id "rekVideoBlog" --detection-attributes "ALL" --external-image-id "<YOURNAME>" --region us-west-2`

I have done this, with my own information input in, but I get an error that states:

Error parsing parameter '--image': Expected: '=', received: ''' for input:
'{S3Object:{Bucket:,Name:.jpeg}}'

I have have looked up what could be the issue, with many solutions involving Windows systems having a different style of quotations compared to the walkthrough (i.e. switching single quotes to doubles and doubles to escaped quotes). No matter what I try, I cannot seem to figure out the issue. Does anyone have an idea of what would be the correct syntax for this on a Windows system or if I am doing something else wrong?

Walkthough: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/easily-perform-facial-analysis-on-live-feeds-by-creating-a-serverless-video-analytics-environment-with-amazon-rekognition-video-and-amazon-kinesis-video-streams/

Comment: If you're using Windows, you'll need to quote using double quotes and escape embedded double quotes: `aws rekognition index-faces --image "{\"S3Object\":{\"Bucket\":\"S3BUCKET\",\"Name\":\"MYFACE_KEY.jpeg\"}}" --collection-id "rekVideoBlog" --detection-attributes "ALL" --external-image-id "YOURNAME" --region us-west-2`

Comment: Forgot to say, but this helped out. Thank you!